# Binding BooleanToVisibilityConverter to an enum in a View Model

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I a View Model, I have:

```
   public enum EventViewMode
   {
       View,
       Update,
       Insert
   }
```

Then, in the view some controls must be visible or not accordiong a value of `EventViewMode`.

For boolean values, I used `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` converter.

Is there a way to use an expression in the binding system to convert the enum value to a boolean expression.

I mean, something like:

```
<Button x:Name="btnSave"  
   Visibility="{Binding MyVariable == EventViewMode.View ,  Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Note that `MyVariable == EventViewMode.View`does not work, it is for showing what I want to reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't I'm afraid.  Your options are

- Use a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)
- Expose the property as a [visbility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of a `EventViewMode`
- Use data triggers to set the desired property (in this case visibility) based on Enum values, for example

  ```
  <Button x:Name="btnSave" Visibility="{Binding MyVariable == EventViewMode.View ,  Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
      <Button.Style>
          <Style TargetType={x:Type Button}>
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyVariable}" Value="View">
                      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                  </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </Button.Style>
  </Button>
  ```

Comment: DataTrigger is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply expose a property in your view model:

```
public bool IsVisible { get { return MyVariable == EventViewMode.View; } }
```

Don't forget to raise property changed notifications for IsVisible when you change MyVariable.

If you don't want to pollute your view model, the next simplest option is to implement another value converter.

Comment: It is how I solved it until now. The problem is when the enum has many values, I need to add many boolean properties in the View Model and also the corresponding chanhged notifications. I would like a more 'clean' solution. Thanks.